# Login as desired user id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Currently have a login merchant developed with [Laravel Sentry packages](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/introduction). 
3 Level of user type, super admin, partner and user. if i want to allow super admin have a feature of login as the partner and edit their panel, how can i do so?

In short, letting super admin mask their id as the id of partner, without having the logout and login with email, password. Please advice what's the exact term for this? I need the right words for search.

Thanks!

Comment: You want admins to be able to try out other users permissions right?

Comment: @oBo, Yep! Use the user session or id of the other user, then browse their content

Comment: check out https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/authentication/login